# Dead pool fatality doesn't work in Mortal Kombat 2

Tags: pc, dos, mortal-kombat-2

I am running good old Mortal Kombat 2 under DosBox :) I have trouble executing the [Dead Pool fatality](https://www.trmk.org/forums/showthread.php/27459-deadpool-fatality-problem):

> hold <kbd>LK</kbd>+<kbd>LP</kbd> then uppercut
>   (<kbd>D</kbd>+<kbd>HP</kbd>)

The fatality doesn't execute. When I try the sequence during the fight situation (not yet the "Finish him" part), it seems that the uppercut itself won't execute. I am holding LK + LP, pressing D will crouch me, but pressing HP won't do anything. **The uppercut wouldn't execute!**

Am I doing anything wrong? Or could this be a keyboard problem? That good old keyboards in those good old days would allow for multiple keys pressed and still send correct codes, but perhaps the new keyboards cannot make it? (Is there no standard for this?)

I am trying it on DELL Latitude D530. The key mapping I have is LK=a, LP=s, D=k, HP=w.

Comment: Check if your keyboard allows multiple keys being pressed at the same time: https://alternativeto.net/software/keyboardtest/

Comment: thanks @galacticninja! I donwloaded `keybord test utility` which confirmed my keyboard cannot do it! If I remap LK=Win, LP=Alt, HK=Z, HP=X, it works! Thanks. Feel free to post an answer.

Comment: @TMS If you want to throw money at solving the problem, you would want to look for keyboards with "N-key rollover" or at least "Two key rollover", which should get rid of the issue.  It's pretty typical on "gaming" keyboards, not necessarily even very high end ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [keyboard testing software](https://alternativeto.net/software/keyboardtest/) to check if your keyboard recognizes multiple keys being pressed at the same time. If your keyboard does not recognize certain keys being pressed at the same time, try remapping to keys that your keyboard does allow.

[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) is also an option to map multiple keys to one key.

Comment: Thanks! I downloaded the keyboard test utility and it confirmed the limit is in my keyboard. I haven't found a comfortable alternative of the keyboard mapping though; the `Win` and `Alt` keys won't work in DosBox...